# How to create exceptions on readspeaker?

Tags: html, accessibility, readspeaker

I'm using readspeaker library on my website for acessibility purposes.

I setted one HTML area () with the id="readable-area". But inside of this  i have some blocks that i don't want to be read.
How can i make an exception for this case?

this is an example code of my situation:

```
...
<!--link to activate the readspeaker-->
<a class="rsbtn_play" accesskey="L" title="Ouvir esta página" href="http://app.eu.readspeaker.com/cgi-bin/rsent?customerid=65437453&amp;readid=readable-area&amp;lang=pt_pt&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fanacom-dev.tangivel.com/30-noticia-r.html">    
  <span class="rsbtn_left rsimg rspart"><span class="rsbtn_text"><span>Listen</span></span></span>
  <span class="rsbtn_right rsimg rsplay rspart"></span>
</a>

<!--Html structure-->
<div id="readable-area">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ut sapien ligula. Proin at maximus orci, a fringilla velit.
   <div class="dont-read">hey don't read me!!</div>
Suspendisse at mollis quam, ut efficitur lacus.
</div>

...
```

I don't want that the readspeaker read what is inside of the class="dont-read" .

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the ReadSpeaker support.

To mute elements from the reading we can use the class="RS_SKIP".
We can find more about the different ways to adjust the reading on http://www.readspeaker.com/hldev/?page_id=10